# Can "origin" be used as an adjective?

Tags: word-usage

I found the following on today's [Wired edition](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/08/forstall-talks-ingenuity-ui/):

> Apple’s Software Boss Reveals the *Origin* Story of iOS

Can *origin* be used as an adjective or some sort of modifier for other words? I couldn't find any source that defines it as an *adjective*.

Am I am being thick or is there something wrong with the title above?

Comment: Is it any different from *creation myth*?

Comment: @TimLymington- I dont know. Could you probably elaborate on that a little bit?

Comment: Why would you have *origin* be an adjective? *School* is not an adjective in *school book*

Comment: @Born2Smile- In school book it acts like one.

Comment: This is an *origin story*, that is, a story about origins, and not an *original story.* You can have *war stories, college stories, football stories*, and so on. None of these words are grammatically classified as adjectives, although they all act like them here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Origin* in this case is not an adjective, but a noun used as an attributive, i.e. a noun being used as a modifier for another noun. This sort of construction is extremely common in English:

- origin story
- creation story
- love story
- horror story

None of the words modifying *story* in the preceding examples are adjectives. They are rather nouns that define the type of the story.

Answer (score 3):

It's a tag* rather than an adjective.  Rather like someone would say "Tell the blonde joke" - i.e. a joke involving a blonde rather than a joke  which is blonde.  "Indolently elliptical" as my English teacher used to write on my papers.

*right word?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an innovation. Normally I'd expect to see *Apple’s Software Boss Reveals the Story of the Origin of iOS.* The OED has *origin* as an adjective only as an obsolete form of *original*.

Comment: "Origin story" is not really an innovation, and "origin" is not being used as an adjective.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ Right, it’s just the regular noun being used attributively.

Comment: Not an innovation.  Anthropology has a whole field of "origin stories".

Comment: "[Origin story](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=origin+story&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Corigin%20story%3B%2Cc0)" seems to have been used since the 1920s at least. A quick glance at some of the earlier examples in Google Books supports GEdgar's comment mentioning its use as a anthropological term

Answer (score -3):

i think origin can be use as adjective because it gives us more details about noun and pronoun we write about.
Origin is the begining or creation
Eg ''paper'' is created or originated from wood
The origin of ''cloth'' is cotton..and many more
If we talk about man,man has his own origin,if we talk about places eg Nigeria it also has its own origin,how it got her name,how it gain independence,how democracy came to Nigeria,her first head of state,prime minister,president and lot more.
Origin tell us more about anything we are writing about.
Adjective also has its own origin

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and see what constitutes a [good answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).